# Attempting to mimic the spacing from another line using \phantom and \mathrel doesn't work

Tags: spacing

Here is an example document.

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\begin{document}

We define two more $B$--symbols, $\zeta_1$ and $\zeta_2$, as follows: for each $x_J \in M(B)$ and each $j \in J$, $\zeta_1(B, J, j)$ and $\zeta_2(B, J, j)$ are integers given by:
    \begin{align*}
           \zeta_1(B, J, j) \; &:= \phantom{2} \mathrel{\phantom{\times}} |\{b \in B : b > j\}|
        \\ \zeta_2(B, J, j) \; &:= 2 \times |\{b \in J : b > j\}|.
    \end{align*}
We define the $B$--symbol $\zeta$ as follows: for each $x_J \in M(B)$ and each $j \in J$, $\zeta(B, J, j)$ is given by $\zeta_1(B, J, j) - \zeta_2(B, J, j)$.

\end{document}
```

Here is a close-up of the output:

[image]

The relevant code used to attempt to add the correct amount of extra spacing is this bit:

```
\phantom{2} \mathrel{\phantom{\times}}
```

But this isn't spaced correctly. It produces slightly too much spacing, as you can see from the picture. How come?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use

```
\phantom{2\times{}}
```

to get the proper spacing. The problem with your code is that `\times` is of type Bin and not Rel and, as egreg has pointed out in his comment, `\mathbin` and `\mathrel` produce different spaces (in general): `\medmuskip` and `\thickmuskip`, respectively. Using `\mathbin` instead of `\mathrel` in your code would have also produced the desired alignment.

Comment: I chose your answer because your solution works, but I am curious as to why my attempted solution didn't work.

Comment: The problem is exactly that `\mathbin` and `\mathrel` produce *different* spaces (in general): `\medmuskip` and `\thickmuskip` (they can be equal only if the glue in the line is stretched), which is not the case inside `align*`.

Comment: @egreg: I've included your comment in my answer. It's really a pleasure to have people like you around here.